# Dependencies conflicts after google-services 15

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use some Google Play services and some extra libraries in the same project. My `app/build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bahir.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


// !!! problematic code  !!!
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

    compile 'com.github.myinnos:AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView:1.0.92'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my `root/build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I delete all 3 Google Play Service libs- it's runing good, or I have to delete this code:

```
 // !!! problematic code  !!!
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and of course:

```
    compile 'com.github.myinnos:AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView:1.0.92'
```

to have a successfully build, I suppose the conflict is into problematic code in `app/build.gradle`, so is there a way to declare `repositories` for a single lirary, in my case for `compile 'com.github.myinnos:AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView:1.0.92'` ???

Answer (score 0):

Use the new plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView using internally '25.3.1' you can exclude

```
compile("com.github.myinnos:AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView:1.0.92") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'      
}
```

Comment: the problem is, Android studio tries to download Google Play services from `jitpack.io` and I get error: `Download https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth-api-phone/maven-metadata.xml 1m 0s 23ms`

Comment: check this once maybe you have to change the version number for play service  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android